# Process files at the exact dir level in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have been searching for a `batch-file` solution to bash command

```
for file in temp/*/*; do ... done
```

Suppose I have a structure:

```
script.bat
temp
---- A
---- fileToExclude1
-------- 0
------------ SomeFile1
------------ SomeFile2
-------- 1
------------ SomeFile3
-------- 2
------------ SomeFile4
---- B
---- fileToExclude2
-------- 0
------------ SomeFile5
-------- 1
------------ SomeFile6
------------ SomeFile7
------------ SomeFile8
------------ SomeFile9
...
```

How can I process files (SomeFile1, SomeFile2, ..., SomeFile9) using analogue command in batch script (or cmd line) to bash command?

Comment: What's the actual question? for file in dir is the right construct

Comment: Yes but (direct cmd line, not script) for %i in (temp\\*\\*) do (echo %i) does nothing.

Comment: The title of post and also the intro statement clearly say that I can get desired files in bash but not batch. So I am looking for batch command that would get me the desired files.

Comment: It does, but your tags and the content does not match that at all.

Comment: Your question is still vague, but I am assuming something like from cmdline like `for /d %i in ("c:\directoryname\*") do for %a in (%i) do echo %a`

Comment: Similar: `for /d %i in ("temp\*") do for /d %j in (%i\*) do for %k in (%j\*) do echo %k` was the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The final solution, based upon advice received [as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203252/process-files-at-the-exact-dir-level-in-a-batch-script/60204595#comment106486863_60203252) by [Gerhard Barnard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7818749/gerhard-barnard) is:

```
for /d %i in ("temp\*") do for /d %j in (%i\*) do for %k in (%j\*) do echo %k
```